# How to find the applications downloaded from the iTunes store

Tags: itunes, osx-mountain-lion, itunes-store

I downloaded an application from the iTunes store.But in my launchpad there isn't this application, I would know where to find it.

Comment: And it's not under `/Applications` through Finder?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications downloaded via the iTunes Store are meant for iOS devices, not your Mac (they wouldn't show up in either Launchpad or in `/Applications/`. You can find the location of your iTunes library by opening iTunes and going to `Preferences > Advanced`. Inside that folder, you should see a `Mobile Applications` folder, where all apps are stored.

If you did mean the Mac App Store, it's possible the application download was interrupted. If you go to the `Purchases` tab, all of the applications you have purchased would be listed, and you should be able to download and install any that are not already marked as such.

Comment: I understand now, I was downloading the apps with os x.I'll do it with my iPhone.Should I remove the downloaded apps?